# Can I use TLS1.2 with an MLLP adapter?

Tags: biztalk, tls1.2, biztalk-2016

I'm being asked to send HL7 messages to an Azure-hosted system using MLLP/TCP with a TLS1.2 connection and client certificate for validation.
Is there a way of making BizTalk use TLS 1.2 with the MLLP adapter on a send port? I can't get it to send anything other than plan text. Or is a VPN the only solution here?

I have BizTalk 2016 CU9 installed and .Net 4.6.2

Comment: Did the below answers help?  If so upvotes to indicate that are appreciated, and if an answer solved your problem, using the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

BizTalk MLLP adapter does not support TLS. One option which is not ideal is to setup a secured VPN tunnel.

It shouldn’t be hard to add this to adapter though by BizTalk product team.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to make BizTalk send ports use TLS 1.2

1. Add a WCF Endpoint Behaviour that set the TLS in code, but the MLLP probably doesn't have this option.
2. Make the .Net Layer use TLS 1.2, and that is through some registry key changes.  Note: That this will make all connections use TLS 1.2 in preferences.   There is also the option of disabling all the older TLS version and Ciphers, but that would require testing all interfaces.  With earlier version of BizTalk that also required upgrading .Net and installing a later version of the SQL Client, but BizTalk 2016 should be fine.  Again, not something you can to with MLLP as it doesn't support TLS at all.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=00000001
```

3. [How to transmit data securely using MLLP adapter](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/16abc3e2-b32e-4fa9-b42f-cda87b8815fb/how-to-transmit-data-securely-using-mllp-adapter?forum=biztalkgeneral) (MSDN Forum), which talks about a VPN tunnel or IPSEC to secure the channel for MLLP

See

- [Support for TLS 1.2 protocol in BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/support-for-tls-1-2-protocol-in-biztalk-server-b142db9a-d071-3d7e-401e-2b2d3d6686ff) (Microsoft)
- [Configure TLS 1.2 On BizTalk Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configure-tls-1-2-on-biztalk-server/) (Article)
- [BizTalk 2016 FP 3 CU6 and TLS 1.2 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548418/biztalk-2016-fp-3-cu6-and-tls-1-2-not-working?rq=1) (StackOverflow)